# jQuery get() AJAX returning only whitespace

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, callback, whitespace

I am trying to make a jQuery get() AJAX call, but the response is just white space. It's not empty, but a series of blank lines, and what appears to be spaces and tabs. Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#package-list a").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var packageID = this.hash.split("#")[1];  //Get the package ID from the link hash, then split off the hash.
  $.get(
    "key-ajax.cfm",
    {n:packageID},   //parameters
    function(data){  //callback
      alert(data);
    }
  );
});
```

And here is the ColdFusion call to the database (key-ajax.cfm):

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8">
<cfquery name="treePackages" datasource="#application.dsn#">
  SELECT id, dateCreated, n, name, fileName, sizeKB
    , product1Name, product1Link, product2Name, product2Link, product3Name, product3Link
  FROM ref_color_keys
  WHERE n = #url.n#
</cfquery>
```

When the response comes back, it looks like an empty box, but I can select "text" inside, which, as I said before, appears to be blank lines, spaces and tabs. If I query the database in a static way, I am able to access the data as expected.

I don't think this is a cross-domain issue, unless it's because I'm calling jQuery from Google's code CDN.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not outputting anything, you're just making a query.

Try this after the query:

```
<cfoutput>#serializeJson(treePackages)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this puts me on the right track. There are an infinite number of examples on how to use get() but I could find no examples on how to actually manipulate the data. Thanks again.